# Make ticket button with css

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have the design and the client wants to make the button only with CSS

[image: ticket button design]

I found a few ways to do it but it's not the same. 
And I can't improve to a perfect copy.

Comment: what you have tired?

Comment: Post whatever you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may use  pseudo-elements  and draw background from their shadow, [example](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GqyqKd):

```css
a {
  margin:3em;
  font-family:arial;
  text-decoration:none;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:1.5em 5em;
  text-transform:uppercase;  
  overflow:hidden;
  color:white;
  border:3px solid white;
  border-left:none;
  border-right:none;
  background:linear-gradient(to left, white 3px, transparent 3px, transparent calc(100% - 3px), white calc(100% - 3px)) top left no-repeat,linear-gradient(to left, white 3px, transparent 3px, transparent calc(100% - 3px), white calc(100% - 3px)) bottom left no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 1.45em;
}

a:before,a:after {
  z-index:-1;
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  height:1.2em;
  width:1em;
  top:1.4em;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:3px solid white;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 10em #102229;
}
a:before {
  left:-0.7em;
}a:after {
  right:-0.7em;
}
b:after {
  content:'>';
  color:#DA153E;
  font-weight:bold;  
  }
body {
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/300);
}
```

```html
<a href="#"> <b>get a free quote </b></a>
```

Comment: Man, thanks a lot! You just save a lot of time, because I'm playng with linear-gradient for the half of the day....Thanks again!