# how can make custom cutout layout component like this in react-native without image?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to create a view as shown in the below image. Is it possible to create a semi circular cropped border view as attached image or link?    https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu2mt.png

`https://codepen.io/verpixelt/pen/cEJLa`

```
code
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/verpixelt/pen/cEJLa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make ticket button with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377113/make-ticket-button-with-css)

Comment: No react native Doesn't support before and after css property